# Integral of components of unit normal vector

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

If we consider a oriented closed hypersurface $\Sigma^{n-1}$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, then 
$$\int_\Sigma\alpha_i\,d\Sigma=0,\ \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\},$$
where $N=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ is the unit normal vector of $\Sigma$.

I wonder if the following is true ou not:
$$\int_\Sigma\alpha_i\alpha_j\,d\Sigma=0,\ i\neq j,\ 1\leq i,j\leq n.$$

On spheres is straightforward verify. But, is true in general case?

Any help or hint is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's definitely not true in general. Spheres have far too much symmetry, so you should be testing more surfaces.

Try the piecewise-smooth surface that is the boundary of the first octant of the unit ball, i.e., $\Sigma = \partial\Omega$, where $\Omega = \{x\in\Bbb R^3: \|x\|\le 1,\ x_i\ge 0 \text{ for } i=1,2,3\}$. You will get a positive integral in each case. If necessary, I believe that you can smooth the surface in a controlled way and continue to have a positive answer.